# Two questions about building packages from source on Manjaro

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

I recently asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103327/manjaro-internet-connection-so-slow-sometimes-doesnt-connect) which was closed for being unclear. I'll ask clear questions now, and I hope to get clear short answers, not a link to Arch Wiki.

I'm on Manjaro Openbox, no Internet, Yaourt isn't installed by default, I need to build packages from source, and not any package, lets be clear, I want to build [this package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/b43-firmware/). I have two questions.

- Is Abs installed by default on Manjaro or do I need to install it before building?

---

- Makepkg: gives permission denied
- Sudo Makepkg: using sudo is a bad idea, use --asroot instead
- Makepkg --asroot: gives permission denied
- pacman -U broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 gives error or the file maybe damaged or something, can't remember, i tried it again and again with different packages and didn't work.

---

So how do you build that particular package on an Arch/Manjaro system?

I want a short answer, Majaro forum users gave me every single page of ArchWiki to read, I don't want to see ArchWiki anymore please, if I was willing to waste a day building packages, I would have gone for Arch, not Manjaro, I think any Manjaro user would have done the same.

---

**Edit** I need fakeroot  to install packages, I can't install base-devel using pacman, no Internet, how to install it from source?

Comment: even if ABS was installed - which I doubt - it wouldn't help. the ABS is for building official packages. _anything_ in the AUR you need to build from source with `makepkg`. broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 is the Broadcom firmware, not a package. the AUR package that you linked to uses that tarball to create the final package. I know you said no Arch Wiki but you _need_ to read the fine documentation on the AUR and the ABS, in order to understand the difference between the two.

Comment: @strugee and how to build broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2 then? I'll read arch wikis when i solve the problem, I'm more interested in solving the problem than getting to know arch, because if i can't solve the problem, I'll remove arch and the arch wikis will not benefit me at all

Comment: Install Ubuntu: that's the only way to solve your problem.

Comment: @jasonwryan  I already have on an external have drive where i store the iso of arch, archbang, manjaro, crunchbang, ubuntu, linux mint debian edition, linux mint, fuduntu and and so many more like kali and backtrack. I just made a decision to go for arch for fun since i tried all the others... Ubuntu is the worst Linux I've ever used, and BTW a member on Manjaro forum has built a custom image for me, has the drivers that i need, and yaourt and base-devel and all, I shall download it and try it tonight, good people are still there and I find that hard to believe...

Comment: If you are going to use Arch, you should be prepared to spend time reading the documentation; it is how the distro and the community works.

Comment: @jasonwryan I'm not using Arch, I'm using Manjaro, which is "Arch made easy" Anyway, I didn't find anything on ArchWiki on "How to install base-devel without internet" that's why I had so much troubles building packages, if base-devel was installed, i could just grab my driver from AUR and install it, the only way to install base-devel is by using the internet as far as i know

Comment: @Fischer download the packages manually from the Manjaro package website (whatever the Manjaro equivalent of packages.archlinux.org is). WRT to "Arch made easy", this is why people (including me) disagree with derivatives like Manjaro. Manjaro is fundamentally different from Arch. if you use an Arch derivative, some of the "power user orientation" will bleed through. I hate to sound condescending but honestly, I'd suggest using a different distribution if you're not willing to read docs. (that's not a bad thing - after all, choices are one of the primary benefits of GNU/Linux!)

Comment: @Fischer "how to build" - untar. `less README`.